# Heroku Rails deployment/build error: Could not find 'bundler' (version) required by your Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler, staging

I have a Ruby on Rails and Redux/React app I have already pushed dozens of times to heroku via "git push heroku master" and it builds correctly. I recently tried to create a staging environment. After setting the remote, I run

```
git push staging master
```

And the webpack portion builds correctly, but once Heroku tries to build the Rails portion I get this error.

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote:  !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_687b8b1cf6d6cbb297288640ccb0d405/Gemfile.lock.
remote:  !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote:  !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote:  !     Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
```

To create the staging environment, I ran

```
heroku create --remote staging
```

in the root folder of the project.

I also have tried updating the bundler.

```
bundle update --bundler
```

&

```
gem install bundler:2.0.1
```

I tried precompiling assets as well, but nothing.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I ran

```
bundle exec rake -P
```

as suggested, but that did not fix it as well.

Another thing is when I push successfully, in the logs it shows I am using a different ruby version

```
Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
```

In the staging logs it shows

```
Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.5
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
```

Not sure if that helps. But any possible solutions can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Does your Gemfile specify a Ruby version? If so, what is it?

Comment: @JakeWorth It doesn't specify in the gemfile actually. I will try to set it as the working ruby version - 2.3.4 and let you know the status. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear @BrianisWinston. I've written this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to issues like these it to ensure all environments (development, staging, production, CI) share the same Ruby version. This will make development and testing much more predictable.

Specify your Ruby version in the Gemfile (this build worked with Ruby 2.3.4, so that's what we'll use):

```rb
# Gemfile

ruby '2.3.4'
```